# Is this derivative wrong?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given the following in WebAssign: $\ y = 8x + {{7} \over {x }} $

Why is it that the derivative is shown to be: $\ {dy \over dx}= {8x^2 - 7 \over { x^2}} $

Yet, when I find the derivative the quotient rule being used on the $\ 7 \over x $ makes my derivative come out to:  $\ {dy \over dx}= {8x^2 +x - 7 \over { x^2}} $

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Derivative of $8x$ is $8$. Derivative of $7/x$ is $-7/x^2$. Now, add those together. I also think you meant $dy/dx$.

Comment: When you do the "quotient rule", there should only be one term, as the derivative of 7 is 0.

Comment: How does 7/x become -7/x^2???

Comment: 7/x = 7*(x^(-1)) $\:$

Comment: Also, are you _sure_ you're supposed to be calculating $\:\frac{dx}{dy}\:$? $\;\;\;$

Comment: I am going to guess that is a typo on his part, but it would be good to know cause the answer will be very different otherwise!

Comment: Sorry, typo. Corrected it. Thanks for your help everyone. Everything is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Amzoti said the derivative of $y = 8x + \frac{7}{x}$ is $\frac{dy}{dx} = 8 - \frac{7}{x^2}$ and you just have to add up the values but if you insist on doing some application of the quotient rule you can add up the terms at first and then derivative.
\begin{eqnarray}
   y & = & 8x + \frac{7}{x} \\
   y & = & \frac{8x^2 + 7}{x}
\end{eqnarray}
Now apply the quotient rule and you should get the solution shown in your textbook or wherever you found that solution.